# Additional Column in ADF through HTTP linked service

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to add an additional column during a copy activity. I cannot use the Getmetadata activity because it is through a hhtp linked service.

However, I am using a parameter called filename in order to specify the file. Would it be possible to input the above parameter in the additional column.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHydB.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot view the Dataset parameter in the pipeline directly.

Alternately you can use a **pipeline parameter** to provide `input` to **Dataset parameter** and use the **same** pipeline parameter in the **Additional Column** value.

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]